# SoftKeyboard in Dialog Activity pans the activity behind

Tags: android, resize, android-softkeyboard, pan, adjustpan

Just as the title says, from one activity I start a dialog activity that contains an editText. When I click it and the softKeyboard comes up, it pans the DialogActivity but it also affects the activity behind.

This is the manifest entry for the parent activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".BasketStep2Activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home.Start"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".home.Start" />
    </activity>
```

and this is the manifest entry for the dialog activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".SelectRelais"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" 
        android:theme="@style/AppDialog" >
    </activity>
```

The parent activity pans to the bottom as if there was an editText with focus there. If i use "adjustResize", everything is obviously messed up. Is there a way to prevent any changes to the background activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use adjustNothing instead of adjustPan in parent activity

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. The weird thing is that this setting is not specified in the Android guide here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html . It seems an important thing to miss, to me.